# A-Frame video in AR not playing

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, virtual-reality

I'm not able to get a video to play in AR mode—has anyone managed to make this work?
[video loads and plays in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUNdv.jpg)
[video is just a black rectangle in AR mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7RDq.jpg)

I'm able to add a video and it plays in the preview panel, but when I test on my Quest Pro I only see a black rectangle. I'm including some code below, and here's a link to my project:
https://shrouded-blush-espadrille.glitch.me

```
<a-assets>
        <video
          id="VIDEO"
          autoplay
          loop="false"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e8fff10e-a82b-4ead-9113-ec7b3bc281e3/SW_01.mp4?v=1673674215025"
        ></video>
      </a-assets>
```

```
<a-video src="#VIDEO" position="-.5 1.5 -1" width="1.3" height=".5" rotation="0 45 0"></a-video>
```

Comment: Does that video have sound? 
It shows only black for me too on iPhone

Comment: @ephb it does indeed have sound. The video plays with sound in the preview window on desktop.

Comment: I think that is your problem. Autoplaying video with sound is not allowed if the user has not clicked on the website yet.